# Trying to update react router 4.0.0 but having issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am getting this error message: `index.js:920 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of Header.`

I have this in my render method:

```
return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route strict path="/" component={Header} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
```

and in header I have

export default class Header extends React.Component {

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ul>
          <div className="links">
            <li><Link to="quizzes">Quizzes</Link></li>
          </div>
          <div className="links">
            <li><Link to="categories">Categories</Link></li>
          </div>
          <div className="links">
            <li><Link to="create">Create</Link></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

so it seems to be saying I haven't exported it but clearly i have. any ideas?

Comment: This error occurs mostly when you wrongly import a component. Please check all your import statements. Could you show the code for import statements of header file?

Comment: sure my import statements of the header component are:

`import React from 'react'; import { Link } from 'react-router'; import './index.scss';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Link component you are importing is from 'react-router' this is the problem, this will work for react-router version < 4.0. From react-router version4 this Link package is part of react-router-dom. So you need to install react-router-dom first:

```
npm install --save react-router-dom
```

import like this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Answer (score 1):

The message is saying "Check the render method of Header".
So the error is in the `Header` component.

My guess is that you imported the `Link` component from `react-router`.
From react-router v4, react-router has split into three packages.
Now `Link` component is living in the `react-router-dom` package.
So you need to install `react-router-dom` and change your import statement to:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
```